# Qual o significado da expressão "mar virado"

Tags: significado, expressões

Por favor, expliquem o que significa a expressão "mar virado".

Comment: Antes de perguntar aqui, procura num dicionário, por favor.  Aqui é preciso mostrar um pequeno esforzo de pesquisa.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is basic meaning that can be found in the dictionary.

Comment: Permitam-me discordar, eu não sei qual é o significado dessa expressão nem encontrei no dicionário. Pode dar mais contexto por favor?

Comment: Depois de ver a resposta e o comentário do Centaurus entendi o significado, aqui em Portugal costumamos dizer que o "mar está bravo".

Answer (score 3):

Significa "mar agitado"; um mar com muitas ondas, violento.

O seguinte significado extraído do [dicionário online Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/virado) se encaixa:

> 6.[Portugual, Informal] **Furioso, zangado. (ex.: só a vi virada uma vez, mas não foi bonito de ver).**

Comment: No Brasil usa-se muito em náutica:  "é melhor não sairmos hoje, o mar está muito virado".

Comment: @Centaurus curioso nunca tinha ouvido isso. Aqui dizemos que o "mar está bravo!"

Comment: @JorgeB.    Aqui também dizemos o mar está bravo ou está muito agitado.  Mas, de um modo geral, conforme eu expliquei, apenas as pessoas que vivem da pesca, o caiçara, ou aqueles que praticam pesca esportiva, dizem que "o mar está virado".

Comment: @Centaurus o que é o caiçara?

Comment: @JorgeB. Caiçaras = praianos; pessoal natural de região costeira.

Comment: @GuiImamura nunca tinha lido nenhuma dessas palavras.

Comment: @JorgeB. Aprendemos algo novo todos os dias :)

Comment: Caiçara é o indivíduo que nasceu e cresceu em região costeira, longe das cidades, e que sempre tirou o seu sustento do mar.